# Fitting three intersecting lines to planar data

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, data-fitting

Suppose I have three sets of points on the plane. Call them the red set, the blue set and the yellow set.

Assume that each set contains at least two distinct points.

I'd like to find three lines - call them the red line, blue line and yellow line - such that:

i) the red, blue and yellow lines have a common point

ii) the red line "fits" the red set as close as possible

iii) the blue line "fits" the blue set as close as possible

iv) the yellow line "fits" the yellow set as close as possible

Note:

1. Without the first condition, this is a standard exercise in linear algebra that usually goes by the term "least-squares minimization".
2. I have in mind some kind of least-squares fit but I'm open to other best fit criteria if they lead to a simpler solution (or any solution).

This is actually a slight simplification of the real problem I am encountering which is a higher dimensional version. In that version, the three sets of data lie in space - not merely a plane - and I am trying to fit the data with three planes that share a common line. I suspect that a solution to the lower dimensional version will readily lead to a solution to the higher dimensional version.

Comment: Should I have posted this on Math Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

While a linear fit, this sounds more like an orthogonal distance problem. I agree that a 2D solution should give the hint how to do it in 3D. With orthogonal distance I actually use a non-linear fit. Looks like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

"""
just some noise
"""
def norm2( s ):
    return np.random.normal( size=2, scale=s )

"""
definition of a line that allows arbitrary slope
actually, for a single line this has an unnecessary parameter,
as 2 should be enough, but with the upcoming restriction in mind, 
that's the one
"""
def lin( t, x0, y0, alpha, disorder=0 ):
    d = np.array( [ x0, y0 ] )
    m = np.array( [ np.cos( alpha ), np.sin( alpha ) ] )
    if isinstance( t, ( float, int ) ):
        out =  d + t * m + norm2( disorder )
    elif isinstance( t, (tuple, list, np.ndarray ) ):
        out = [ d + item * m + norm2( disorder ) for item in t ]
    else:
        raise TypeError
    return np.asarray( out )

"""
test data
"""
tl = np.linspace( -7, 7, 25 )
pl1 = lin( tl, 3, 4, +0.133, disorder=0.1 )
pl2 = lin( tl, 3, 4, -1.150, disorder=0.1 )
pl3 = lin( tl, 3, 4, +1.513, disorder=0.1 )

"""
distance from line to point whre line is given by r + m * t 
and ||m|| = 1
(actually the least sqaure function is sqaring that again later, but ok )
"""
def dist_lin_pnt( r, m, p ):
    q = p - r
    q2 = np.dot( q, q )
    mq = np.dot( m, q )
    d2 = q2 - mq**2
    return np.sqrt( d2 )

"""
residual function
no weighting introduced here, but if different lines or points
have different weights, that should be easy to change
"""
def res( params, line1, line2, line3 ):
    x0, y0, a, b, g = params
    r = np.array( [ x0, y0 ] )
    m1 = np.array( [ np.cos( a ), np.sin( a ) ] )
    m2 = np.array( [ np.cos( b ), np.sin( b ) ] )
    m3 = np.array( [ np.cos( g ), np.sin( g ) ] )
    dist1 = [ dist_lin_pnt( r, m1, p ) for p in line1 ]
    dist2 = [ dist_lin_pnt( r, m2, p ) for p in line2 ]
    dist3 = [ dist_lin_pnt( r, m3, p ) for p in line3 ]
    return np.array( dist1 + dist2 + dist3 )

"""
Solution is quite stable w.r.t starting conditions
"""
solution = least_squares(
    res,
    x0=( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ),
    args=( pl1, pl2, pl3 )
)
print( solution.x )
xf, yf, af, bf, gf = solution.x
pl1f = lin( tl, xf, yf, af )
pl2f = lin( tl, xf, yf, bf )
pl3f = lin( tl, xf, yf, gf )

"""
plotting the data
"""
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )

ax.plot( pl1[ ::, 0 ], pl1[ ::, 1 ], ls="", marker="o", color="r" )
ax.plot( pl2[ ::, 0 ], pl2[ ::, 1 ], ls="", marker="o", color="b" )
ax.plot( pl3[ ::, 0 ], pl3[ ::, 1 ], ls="", marker="o", color="y" )

ax.plot( pl1f[ ::, 0 ], pl1f[ ::, 1 ], color="r" )
ax.plot( pl2f[ ::, 0 ], pl2f[ ::, 1 ], color="b" )
ax.plot( pl3f[ ::, 0 ], pl3f[ ::, 1 ], color="y" )

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to choose a common vector `c`, and `G` vectors `d[g[i]]` where `g[i]` denotes the group of the point `v[i]`, you want to minimize `|d[g[i]] * t[i] - v[i] - c|`, by choosing `d`, `t` and `c`. Notice the product of two variables `d[g[i]] * t[i]`, in general the problem is not convex anymore.

You could simply drop this in a non-linear optimization

Maybe if you assume `t[i] > 0` you could find a convex formulation for this (guessing here).

You can try some heuristic approach, for instance, you can start solving individual linear regression problems, given the solutions find the point `c` that minimize the sum squared residual to all the lines, then you add this point to all the set of points, and fit again, repeating the weight of the added points start to increase, and hopefully you will find a good solution.